# Will "single" operation tasks run slower in GHCI?

Tags: haskell

I'm doing some very high number computations, mostly involving 2^x where x > 200 million and this usually takes about 20 seconds per calculation in GHCI (without printing it, of course) Would this benefit significantly from compiling, since it's mostly based on memory? Significantly for me would be > 2x as fast

Comment: What happened when you did try to compile it?

Comment: It was nearly identical speeds for that operation, if not more sometimes. This is mostly an academic question, though. If I want to do something as fast as possible, I'll compile it :)

Comment: If you want something as fast as possible, you have to take into account the time it takes you to compile the code :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the performance of both will be the same.

For computations with large integers, GHC simply calls into the bignum library, which is often LibGMP (although a pure Haskell alternative is now available), and LibGMP will always be the same speed no matter whether the code calling LibGMP is compiled to native code or interpreted.

You will only see speedups by compiling if you spend a larger percentage of time outside LibGMP.

Comment: This is exactly what I was wondering. Thanks! I'll accept your answer when SO let's me ;)